# How to sort files numerically from linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line, sorting

Okay, now this is more a rant about Linux than a question, but maybe someone knows how to do what I want. I know this *can* be *achieved* using the `sort` command, but I want a better solution because getting that to work is about as easy as writing a C program to do the same thing.

I have files, for arguments sake, lets say I have these files: (my files are the same I just have many more)

- file-10.xml
- file-20.xml
- file-100.xml
- file-k10.xml
- file-k20.xml
- file-k100.xml
- file-M10.xml
- file-M20.xml
- file-M100.xml

Now this turns out to be the order I want them sorted in. Incidentally, this is the order *in Windows* that they are by default sorted into. That's nice. Windows groups consecutive numerical characters into *one effective character* which sorts alphabetically before letters.

If I type `ls` at the linux command line, I get the following garbage. Notice the 20 is displaced. This is a bigger deal when I have hundreds of these files that I want to view in a report, in order.

- file-100.xml
- file-10.xml
- file-20.xml
- file-k100.xml
- file-k10.xml
- file-k20.xml
- file-M100.xml
- file-M10.xml
- file-M20.xml

I can use `ls -1 | sort -n -k 1.6` to get the ones without 'k' or 'M' correct...

- file-k100.xml
- file-k10.xml
- file-k20.xml
- file-M100.xml
- file-M10.xml
- file-M20.xml
- file-10.xml
- file-20.xml
- file-100.xml

I can use `ls -1 | sort -n -k 1.7` to get none of it correct

- file-100.xml
- file-10.xml
- file-20.xml
- file-k10.xml
- file-M10.xml
- file-k20.xml
- file-M20.xml
- file-k100.xml
- file-M100.xml

Okay, fine. Let's really get it right. `ls -1 | grep "file-[0-9]*\.xml" | sort -n -k1.6 && ls -1 file-k*.xml | sort -n -k1.7 && ls -1 file-M*.xml | sort -n -k1.7`

- file-10.xml
- file-20.xml
- file-100.xml
- file-k10.xml
- file-k20.xml
- file-k100.xml
- file-M10.xml
- file-M20.xml
- file-M100.xml

Whew! Boy glad the "power of the linux command line" saved me there. (This isn't practical for my situation, because instead of `ls -1` I have a command that is another line or two long)

Now, the Windows behavior is simple, elegant, and does what you want it to do 99% of the time. Why can't I have that in linux? Why oh why does `sort` not have a "automagic sort numbers in a way that doesn't make me bang head into wall" switch?

Here's the pseudo-code for C++:

```
bool compare_two_strings_to_avoid_head_injury(string a, string b)
{
    string::iterator ai = a.begin();
    string::iterator bi = b.begin();
    for(; ai != a.end() && bi != b.end(); ai++, bi++)
    {
        if (*ai is numerical)
            gobble up the number incrementing ai past numerical chars;
        if (*bi is numerical)
            gobble up the number incrementing bi past numerical chars;
        actually compare *ai and *bi and/or the gobbled up number(s) here
            to determine if we need to compare more chars or can return the 
            answer now;
    }
    return something here;
}
```

Was that so hard? Can someone put this in sort and send me a copy? Please?

Comment: You could have saved yourself a bit of pain by padding the
numeric fields to the same length with leading zeroes, instead
of relying on platform-specific quirks to get the sort order you want.  Just sayin'....

Comment: I will point out that maybe the Windows behavior does what _you_ want it to do 99% of the time, but it's not fair to say that it does what everyone wants 99% of the time. As a matter of fact I could just as well make the same complaint about Windows' sorting that you've made about Linux's sorting. (It would be nice to have this as an _option_ to `sort` though)

Comment: What is the programming question here? If you just want to sort filenames, somebody at http://superuser.com might be able to help.

Comment: Windows did not always sort this way.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319827

Comment: @Jim Lewis, A) I never relied on any platform specific behavior at any point in my process, and yet this still came up, amazing, right? B) you're totally missing the point.

Now on the other hand, if you would like to go through and rename the hundreds of files that I already have, I would be more than obliged :)

Instead of acknowledging it as a problem with linux (which it is, the entire sort -n -k key stuff is total BS), apparently the answer is "Bad user! Don't do it that way! Go back and recreate everything knowing what you were going to do with it in the future!"

Comment: @Scott: yes you did use a platform-specific quirk, namely the fact that `dir` groups consecutive numbers into an "effective character" whereas `ls` doesn't. Although technically it's a quirk of the `dir` program, not of Windows. Similarly, what you call a problem with Linux is actually a "problem" with one particular program, `sort`. (And besides, it's not a problem in the same way that a legitimate bug is a problem, it's just a design decision that happens to not match your requirements. That happens from time to time on every platform.)

Comment: @David, No. I did not rely on platform specific quirks. Even if I did, an attitude of blame the user won't help. My entire point is that sort is broken (ok I won't say "linux"), as it needs a better way to sort numbers in files. The current way, which involves counting the characters in front of your numbers, is just total crap. And I'm rather surprised a better way is not in there. I spent a lot of time looking for one assuming it must be. Given the endless number of linux command line programs, the best way is apparently the many command sed chain I used below??? Good grief!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be my first thought:

```
ls -1 | sed 's/\-\([kM]\)\?\([0-9]\{2\}\)\./-\10\2./' | sort | sed 's/0\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1/'
```

Basically I just use `sed` to pad the number with zeros and then use it again afterwards to strip off the leading zero.

I don't know if it might be quicker in Perl.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, based on your suggestion. I have this since I needed up to 4 digits `for f in \`ls -1 $1*.xml | sed -r 's/-([kM]?)([0-9]{4})\./-\10\2./; s/-([kM]?)([0-9]{3})\./-\100\2./; s/-([kM]?)([0-9]{2})\./-\1000\2./; s/-([kM]?)([0-9]{1})\./-\10000\2./' | sort | sed -r 's/0+([1-9])/\1/'\`; do` which I find to be thoroughly ridiculous for such a simple task. It's a large failing of `sort` IMO.

Answer (score 37):

Try
    sort --version-sort -f

- file-10.xml
- file-20.xml
- file-100.xml
- file-k10.xml
- file-k20.xml
- file-k100.xml
- file-M10.xml
- file-M20.xml
- file-M100.xml

The -f option is to ignore case (otherwise, it would put the k's and M's in the wrong order in this example). However, I don't think sort isn't properly interpreting the letters k and M as thousands and millions, if that was your goal - its just alphabetical order.

Comment: Much better solution than the selected answer...maybe less portable I guess.  `-V` is the short flag for `--version-sort`, for reference.

Answer (score 16):

`ls -1v` will get you pretty close.  It just sorts all capital letters before lower case.

Comment: This is working for numerics having different digit size as well: `1 2 3 ... 12 13 14 ... 123 124 125 ... 1123 1124 1125 ...`